# How to capture values from multiple select drop downs on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm very new to Jquery so please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

My page has 20 categories. Each category has a select drop down offering a product option. The user will select a product option from each category. Each time an option is selected an ajax call will be made using the product_id (the value) to get the price. Then another selection made and another.

Problem: My PHP works. However, my JQuery is not getting the unique product_id (value) from each selection. It will get perhaps the values from the first select. Then the 2nd or 3rd select are either empty or repeats of the first.

I have tried using discrete #id's, classes, and input types. and have not be able to solve the problem. It is probably irrelevant but I am using Bootstrap and Laravel as well.

**Jquery** - the ajax call is omitted. At the moment I am just trying to get correct values.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 $(".product_id" ).blur(function() {
 var value = null;            // this is intended to clear the previous value. 
 var value = $(".product_id").val()
 console.log('value', value);
});
})
```

Sample of Page View:

```
<div class="collapse " id="Materials">
<div class="well form-group  ">
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">{!! Form::label('materials1', 'Materials:') !!}</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">{!! Form::select('product_code[1]',$products,null,['class'=>'form-control product_id','placeholder'=>'None']) !!}</div>
 <div class="col-sm-2  col-md-2">{!! Form::label('req1', 'Requirements:') !!}</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">{!! Form::text('quantity[1]',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}</div>
 </div>

 <div class="well form-group  ">
 <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">{!! Form::label('materials2', 'Materials:') !!}</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">{!! Form::select('product_code[2]', $materials,null, ['class'=>'form-control product_id','placeholder'=>'None']) !!}</div>
 <div class="col-sm-2  col-md-2">{!! Form::label('req2', 'Requirements:') !!}</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">{!! Form::text('quantity[2]',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}</div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the interpreted HTML? I'm guessing `{!! Form::label('materials1', 'Materials:') !!}` resolves to `<label id='materials1'>Materials</label>`, but can you please post it, to be clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".product_id" ).change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log('value: '+ value);
  });
});
```

Can I add that you will most likely want to use the `.change` method [(doc)](https://api.jquery.com/change/) instead of `.blur` [(doc)](https://api.jquery.com/blur/). `.blur` requires the element to loose focus, or in other words, the user must tab, or click somewhere else for the `.blur` event to trigger. `.change` will trigger after a selection has been made.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".product_id" ).change(function() {
   var value = $(this).val();
    alert('value: '+ value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse " id="Materials">
  <div class="well form-group  ">
    <form>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        <label id='materials1'>Materials</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <select class='product_id'>
          <option>Gold</option>
          <option>Copper</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2  col-md-2">
        <label id='req1'>Requirements</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <input type='text' />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="well form-group  ">
    <from>
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        <label id='materials2'>Materials</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <select class='product_id'>
          <option>Silver</option>
          <option>Ore</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2  col-md-2"><label id='req2'>Requirements</label></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4"><input type='text' /></div>
    </from>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are a Rockstar - Many thanks !! I am comfortable with PHP / Laravel / Codeigniter .... but for some darned reason, JS and JQuery are just an enigma to me ... Many thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

I have some ideas for you. First, you don't need to set var value = null. When you are declaring var value = whatever you are declaring a new variable that wont have any old values. Second you want to set value to $(this).val because you want the value of the .product_id that has blur'ed. 
I think you want your js to look like this:

```
$(".product_id" ).blur(function() {
 var value = $(this).val();
 console.log('value' + value);
});
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply - you have helped me greatly understand a little more about JQuery ! Cheers !